# Excel VBA check if sheet exists and if yes add numeric to sheet name

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I would like to say i'm an intermediate user of Excel VBA but i'm struggling with this one.

I have written a script to read a text file and strip out all the information I need and then add it to Worksheet that is named by the text file name and then todays date.

```
Set WS1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
myFileName = FileNameOf(myFile)
WS1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set WS2 = ActiveSheet
strNewSheetName = myFileName & " - " & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YY")
blnSheetCheck = CheckIfSheetExists(strNewSheetName)
If blnSheetCheck = True Then
    blnDeleteSheet = MsgBox("NOTICE:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This text file has already been added today!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "would you like to delete the existing one?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
    If blnDeleteSheet = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strNewSheetName).Delete
        WS2.Name = strNewSheetName
    Else
    ' Roll the number here
    End If
Else
    WS2.Name = strNewSheetName
End If
```

I use this function to check if it exists

```
Function CheckIfSheetExists(SheetName) As Boolean

CheckIfSheetExists = False
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set WS99 = Sheets(SheetName)
If Err = 0 Then
    CheckIfSheetExists = True
Else
    CheckIfSheetExists = False
End If

End Function
```

When I first wrote the code I was going to add a time to the sheet name but it will sometimes push the name over the 31 character limit.

So I would like some guidance on how I can add a numeric to the end of the sheet name and then repeat the process to see if that sheet name exists and then move it up a number and then check again.

Thank you in advance

Andy

Comment: single integer 0 -9? ie no more than 10 sheets in any one date?

Comment: Maybe add the integer to the front of the sheet name followed by `:` or other deliminator. Then when comparing, if a sheet name has the deliminator, see if the text following can be found (at location 1) in the sheet name you're checking for duplicates of. Then, even if some of the end text is lost, you can assume it matched because the existing text matches. (**Downside:** if the names only vary at the end of the name, those differences could be lost)

Comment: @HarassedDad yes a simple integer to the end of the sheetname will do the job

Comment: @Mistella I can't see there being any more than 2 text files being added on any set day but would like to have the option to at least go to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will name the sheets as, for example:
`Test 03-05-18` and then `Test 03-05-18_01` up to `Test 03-05-18_99`.

Update this line to allow more copies:
`TempShtName = SheetName & "_" & Format(lCounter, "00")`

There's one procedure and two functions in the code:
The first is a copy of your code (with variables declare).
The second figures out the name of the sheet.
The third checks if the sheet exists.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim WrkBk As Workbook
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myFileName As String

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    'File name including extension:
    'myFileName = Mid(myFile, InStrRev(myFile, "\") + 1)

    'File name excluding extension:
    myFileName = Mid(myFile, InStrRev(myFile, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myFile, ".") - InStrRev(myFile, "\") - 1)

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Home")
        WS1.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)

        Set WS2 = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        WS2.Name = GetSheetName(myFileName & " - " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy"))
    End With

End Sub

'Return a numbered sheet name (or the original if it's the first).
Public Function GetSheetName(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As String

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim TempShtName As String
    Dim lCounter As Long

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    TempShtName = SheetName
    Do While WorkSheetExists(TempShtName)
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
        TempShtName = SheetName & "_" & Format(lCounter, "00")
    Loop

    GetSheetName = TempShtName

End Function

'Check if the sheet exists.
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**Edit:** 
To remove illegal characters and keep the sheet name to 31 characters you could add this code in the `GetSheetName` function just before the `TempShtName = SheetName` line:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim sChr As String
Const ILLEGAL_CHR As String = "\/*?:[]"

For x = 1 To Len(SheetName)
    sChr = Mid(SheetName, x, 1)
    If InStr(ILLEGAL_CHR, sChr) > 0 Then
        SheetName = Replace(SheetName, sChr, "_")
    End If
Next x
If Len(SheetName) > 28 Then
    SheetName = Left(SheetName, 28)
End If
```

Comment: Cheers fella. I have check with the people that are going to using it and they are not sure if they will all legal characters in the text name, and even went as far to say that some of them have the [] brackets so i'm going to try your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WS1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
myFileName = FileNameOf(myFile)
WS1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set WS2 = ActiveSheet
strNewSheetName = myFileName & " - " & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YY")
blnSheetCheck = CheckIfSheetExists(strNewSheetName)
If blnSheetCheck = True Then
    blnDeleteSheet = MsgBox("NOTICE:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This text file has already been added today!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "would you like to delete the existing one?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
    If blnDeleteSheet = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strNewSheetName).Delete
        WS2.Name = strNewSheetName
    Else
     '======Here's the new bit=================
       Dim x as integer
       x = 1
       Do
           strnewsheetname = left(strnewsheetname,30) & x
           blnSheetCheck = CheckIfSheetExists(strNewSheetName)
           x = x +1
       Loop while blnSheetCheck
       WS2.Name = strNewSheetName
    '=============End of New Bit=============
    End If

Else
    WS2.Name = strNewSheetName
End If
```

Technically this will keep looping above 9, but from you've said I don't think this will be a problem

Comment: I have 2 Command buttons on the copy from page (home) how do i copy it without the command buttons ?

Comment: After the line Set WS2 = ActiveSheet you could add

Dim c As Shape

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Shapes

c.Delete

Next c

Assuming there are no  other shapes on the sheet